# Exuberant as an adjective

Tags: word-usage

Can you use "exuberant" as an adjective to describe someone excitement and enthusiastic about something?  Also, does the word associates with positive or negative connotation?

Here is the sentence where I used exuberant:

> I am so thrilled to know that at least one of the paradigms got your attention and so exuberant about the possibility of implementing this experiment.

Some context: I have proposed a research idea and the principle investigator thinks it's worth pursuing, so do you think it conveys that meaning?

Comment: As a learner: To me exuberant convey a sense of physical vivaciousness or being energetic. So, personally I wouldn't use it to imply excitement.

Comment: So, what would you suggest instead of exuberant? Something other than enthusiastic!

Comment: You already used *excited* in your question. What's wrong with that?